# determine which word from an array is in a string

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$str = "Hello is a greeting";
```

And I have an array of words:

```
$equals = array("is", "are", "was", "were", "will", "has", "have", "do", "does");
```

I'm trying to see which word is in the string:

```
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$new_association = false;
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $equals)) {
        $new_association = true;
        $e['response'] = 'You made an association.';
        // determine which 'equals' word was used.      
        // $equal_used = 'is';
    }
}
```

How do I determine which equals word was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark's answer above is superior but if you'd rather stick with your current approach:

```
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$new_association = false;
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $equals)) {
        $new_association = true;
        $e['response'] = 'You made an association.';
        // determine which 'equals' word was used.      
        $equal_used = $word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_asscociation = false;
$equal_used = array_intersect($equals, explode(' ', $str)); 
if (!empty($equal_used)) { 
    $new_asscociation = true; 
    var_dump($equal_used); 
}
```

Comment: What if I just want the value which is present as a string?

Comment: If there's more than one value, which one do you want as a string.

Comment: But you could do `$equal_used = implode(' ', $equal_used);` to create a string